# Redis unable to parse input: Expected Whitespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-memory-db

I am using AWS' Redis MemoryDB 7 Preview with Vector Search enabled. The following queries fail for me with a strange error:

```bash
# create an index
FT.CREATE idx ON JSON SCHEMA $.title AS title TEXT

# add a document
JSON.SET doc $ '{"title":"hello"}'

# search for the document
FT.SEARCH idx "@title:hello"
```

This fails with the following error:

```
(error) ERR Parse error at 0 Unexpected `@` Expected whitespaces
```

However `FT.SEARCH idx *` works fine. I have tried setting `export TERM=dumb` because I thought that the terminal is escaping some characters incorrectly.

The Redis Engine on the MemoryDB is 7.1, my `redis-cli` 7.2.3.